# How to turn an array of objects into an object in mongodb aggregation

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I had asked [this question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60740127/how-to-group-arrays-based-on-another-array-in-mongodb-aggregation) and I got a [satisfactory answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60767035/9953550). But I have a new problem that I am unable to solve.

The output I am getting from the [query](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60767035/9953550) is an array of objects. How can I turn that array into an object? I already know [how to do it in plain javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50941117/9953550) but how can I do it in a mongodb aggregation query?

You can assume that you have the data below in the aggregation query.

```
[
    {  "choiceA": [
            {"_id": ObjectId("..."), "voter": "Juzi", "choice": 0, "pollId": 100 },
            {"_id": ObjectId("..."), "voter": "Juma", "choice": 0, "pollId": 100 },
            {"_id": ObjectId("..."), "voter": "Jane", "choice": 0, "pollId": 100 },
    ]},
    {  "choiceB": [
            {"_id": ObjectId("..."), "voter": "Jamo", "choice": 1, "pollId": 100 },
            {"_id": ObjectId("..."), "voter": "Juju", "choice": 1, "pollId": 100 },
            {"_id": ObjectId("..."), "voter": "Jana", "choice": 1, "pollId": 100 }
    ]},
    {  "choiceC": [ ] }
]
```

How do I turn it into an object to look like below

```
{
    "choiceA": [
            {"_id": ObjectId("..."), "voter": "Juzi", "choice": 0, "pollId": 100 },
            {"_id": ObjectId("..."), "voter": "Juma", "choice": 0, "pollId": 100 },
            {"_id": ObjectId("..."), "voter": "Jane", "choice": 0, "pollId": 100 },
    ],
    "choiceB": [
            {"_id": ObjectId("..."), "voter": "Jamo", "choice": 1, "pollId": 100 },
            {"_id": ObjectId("..."), "voter": "Juju", "choice": 1, "pollId": 100 },
            {"_id": ObjectId("..."), "voter": "Jana", "choice": 1, "pollId": 100 }
    ],
    "choiceC": [ ] 
}
```

Or you can just answer [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60740127/how-to-group-arrays-based-on-another-array-in-mongodb-aggregation) with the result above as the output. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add these steps to your pipeline:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: null,
      x: {
        $push: "$$ROOT"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      x: {
        $mergeObjects: "$x"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $replaceRoot: {
      newRoot: "$x"
    }
  }
])
```

[MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/ewhNjpSd7G2)

Comment: Hi @Valijon, Kindly check this other [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62878339/9953550). Thank you.